# What is the difference between withTransaction and withNewTransaction?

Tags: hibernate, grails, transactions, grails-2.0

What is the difference between the following actions?

```
def someAction() {
  User.withTransaction { ... } 
}
```

and

```
def someAction() {
  User.withNewTransaction { ... }
}
```

1. When do I use what?
2. When a grails action contains only a Transaction block. In this case I guess withTransaction and withNewTransaction are the same, because each action has its own transaction. Is this true?

Comment: I would imagine that the first variant would participate in an existing transaction if one existed or start one if not and the second one always starts a new transaction regardless of if one is already exexuting

Comment: I updated my question. What do you think about question 2?

Comment: I Agree with @cmbaxter, just a side note: controllers should be as simple as possible, just handling requests. If you need to work with transactions a service is a better place (they already are transactional).

Answer (score 13):

I believe these functions have to do with transaction isolation semantics.  The `withTransaction` function will participate in an existing transaction if one already has been started and would start a new one if not.  The `withNewTransaction` method will always start a new transaction regardless of if one has already been started, isolating the code inside that block into it's own transaction (with its own commit/rollback).

If you think the method you are developing should or could participate in some larger transaction with multiple separate db writes, then you should use `withTransaction` so that you can participate in a larger transaction if necessary.  If you want your write here to be totally isolated from other db writes if another transaction is going on (and not potentially roll back that other transaction if this code fails), then use `withNewTransaction`.

In regards to your question two, these two will behave the same if they are the only calls being made in an action as they would both start up a new transaction.

Comment: Do you know or have any reference docs in which I could look for whether `withNewTransaction` uses a new thread for that other separate transaction or not?