# Handling Grails transactions programmatically

Tags: hibernate, grails, transactions, grails-orm

When I need to save a list of objects, and each object should be saved in it's own transaction (so that if one fails they don't all fail), I do it like this:

```
List<Book> books = createSomeBooks()
books.each { book ->
  Book.withNewSession {
    Book.withTransaction {TransactionStatus status ->
      try {
        book.save(failOnError: true)
      } catch (ex) {
        status.setRollbackOnly()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I use `Book.withNewSession` because if one book fails to save and the transaction is rolled back, the session will be invalid which will prevent subsequent books from saving. However, there are a couple of problems with this approach:

1. It's a bit verbose
2. A new session will always be created for each book, even if the previous book succeeded

Is there a better way? One possibility that occurred to me is to dependency-inject the Hibernate `SessionFactory` and do this instead

```
List<Book> books = createSomeBooks()
books.each { book ->
  try {
    Book.withTransaction {
      book.save(failOnError: true)
    }
  } catch (ex) {
    // use the sessionFactory to create a new session, but how....?
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would you need to create a new session for each iteration? IMHO is sufficent to execute only withTransaction block in each iteration, but all can happen in one session..

Comment: @lukelazarovic I only need a new session if a rollback occurs. The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to create a new session in the catch block

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should do it:

```
List<Book> books = createSomeBooks()
books.each { book ->
  Book.withNewTransaction {TransactionStatus status ->
    try {
      book.save(failOnError: true)
    } catch (ex) {
      status.setRollbackOnly()
    }
  }
}
```

The session isn't invalid if you rollback, it is just cleared. So any attempts to access entities read from the DB would fail, but writes of not-yet-persisted entities will be just fine. But, you do need to use separate transactions to keep one failure from rolling back everything, hence the withNewTransaction.

Comment: any idea what the difference between `withNewTransaction` and `withTransaction` is? The former isn't documented.

Comment: [Difference mentioned here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17994623/2051952) and [plan is to move this to documents in 2.4](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7093). Look for comments from Graeme. I wonder why it has not made to documents. Burt has covered this method in his book. @Don

Comment: If you dump the TransactionStatus object, there is a Boolean property named newTransaction. Apparently for withTransaction this is set to false. And based on behavior (using only an arbitrary setRollbackOnly to simulate a failure), it does seem to use a single transaction unless you use withNewTransaction.

Comment: Also, I see you asked a similar question previously http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21638706/grails-programmatic-transaction-handling?rq=1, with more detail it seems. Were you getting the lazy initialization exception because you were trying to access entities previously read from the DB, because you were trying to update them? If so, perhaps you could retrieve each existing record as part of the transaction instead of all at once in the beginning, to ensure they don't all get cleared if there is a write failure?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try validating them first, and then saving all the ones that passed?  I'm not sure if it's any more performant, but it may be a little cleaner.  Something like:

```
List<Book> books = createSomeBooks()
List<Book> validatedBooks = books.findAll { it.validate() }
validatedBooks*.save()
```

Although I'm not sure if `.validate()` promises the save won't fail for other reasons, and if the data is independent (ie a unique constraint passes until the next book tries to save as well).

Comment: I don't think this is reliable, because as you pointed out there's no guarantee that a validated object will actually save, because the state of the database could be different between when the object is validated and when it is saved.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use groovy meta-programming & grails dynamic domain methods?

In Bootstrap:

```
    def grailsApplication

    def init = {

    List.metaClass.saveCollection = {
        ApplicationContext context = (ApplicationContext) ServletContextHolder.getServletContext().getAttribute(GrailsApplicationAttributes.APPLICATION_CONTEXT);
        SessionFactory sf = context.getBean('sessionFactory')
        Session hsession = sf.openSession()
        def notSaved = []
        delegate.each {
            if(!it.trySave()) {
                notSaved << it
                hsession.close()
                hsession = sf.openSession()
            }
        }
        hsession.close()
        return notSaved
    }

    grailsApplication.getArtefacts("Domain")*.clazz.each { clazz ->
        def meta = clazz.metaClass
        meta.trySave = {
            def instance = delegate
            def success = false
            clazz.withTransaction { TransactionStatus status ->
                try {
                    instance.save(failOnError: true) // ', flush: true' ?
                    success = true
                } catch (ex) {
                    status.setRollbackOnly()
                }
            }
            return success
        }
    }
    }
```

And then:

```
class TheController {
    def index() {
        List<Book> books = createSomeBooks()

        def notSaved = books.saveCollection()
        books.retainAll { !notSaved.contains(it) }

        println "SAVED: " + books
        println "NOT SAVED: " + notSaved
    }
}
```

Of course there must be some checks performed (e.g. list contains domain classes, etc.). You can also pass to closures specific params to make this more flexible (e.g. `flush`, `failOnError`, `deepValidate`, etc.)