# Wait for lock release in Grails transaction

Tags: spring, grails, groovy

I'm trying to write a Groovy/Grails 3 function that looks up a database object, locks it, and then saves it (releasing the lock automatically).

If the function is called multiple times, it should wait until the lock is released, and then run the update.  How can I accomplish this?

```
def updateUser(String name) {
  User u = User.get(1)
  // if locked, wait until released somehow?
  u.lock()
  u.name = name
  u.save()
}

updateUser('bob')
updateUser('fred') // sees lock from previous call, waits until released, then updates
```

Comment: you need .withNewTransaction did a recent answer couldn't find it. here is an older one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805893/handling-grails-transactions-programatically. Don't think you need to  bother locking record. Wrap it around .withNewTransaction. This also means if you query it straight after - you may need to do same...

Answer (score 0):

`u.save(flush:true)`

Flushing the Hibernate session should complete the transaction and release the lock on the database level.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, [pessimistick locking](http://gorm.grails.org/6.0.x/hibernate/manual/index.html#locking) only works in a [transactional context](https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/services.html#declarativeTransactions).
So make sure to put the updateUser method in a service that is annotated with @Transactional.

Calling get() and then lock() results in 2 sql statements being executed (one for getting the object, another for locking it).
Using User.lock(), a single select ... for udpate query is issued instead.

```
@Transactional
class UserService {
    def updateUser(String name) {
      User u = User.lock(1) // blocks until lock is free
      u.name = name
      u.save()
    }
}
```